# What is the correct equation to find x and y coordinates based on angle and distance?

Tags: javafx, coordinates, trigonometry, equation

I am trying to implement a program in JavaFX. I have an image of a jet, which can rotate 360 around its center axis. I have translated the x, y coordinates from the top left, to the center. The idea is when I move the image forward, it draws a line from its starting position to the new location in the direction the image is pointing. I can get the current angle using the getRotate() method on the node, which is taken as 0/360 at the 12 o'clock position. The angle is in degrees but not a prob to swap to radiens if necessary. The start x, y coordinates are at the image center. Problem is I do not know the correct equation to use to get the full 360, using the FX pane, which has the origin 0, 0 in the upper left corner, increasing in value to the right and down.
I have tried using endX = startX + (cos(angle) and endY = startY + (sin(angle) but it dosent work. the lines are drawn on the opposite side to what they should be, or so it seems, and the angles are wrong also, not in line with the image center axis (as can be seen in the image went backwards and is out of alignment. think they are going counter clockwise when they need to be clockwise. At least that is what seems to be happening.
Any ideas?

```
        //FxTimer.runPeriodically(Duration.ofMillis(turtleSpeed), () -> {
            double startX = imageView.getX();
            double startY = imageView.getY();
            double endX = (startX + (distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(imageView.getRotate()))));
            double endY = (startY + (distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(imageView.getRotate()))));
            this.imageView.setX(endX);
            this.imageView.setY(endY);
            if(!(penUp)) {
                Line line = new Line(startX, startY, endX, endY);
                line.setStroke(penColour);
                this.getChildren().add(line);
                imageView.toFront();
            }
```

EDIT I have moved the origin to the center of the pane and converted to radiens, still no joy. The line lines up fine now, but the movement of the image is 90 degrees 'out of phase'

[image]

Comment: The `rotate` property gives the angle in degrees, and IIRC it's measured clockwise. The standard Java functions `Math.sin(...)` and `Math.cos(...)` expect an angle in radians, and your equations will interpret it as an angle measured counter-clockwise. So you'll need to do some conversion. Also, your equations assume a distance of 1 (pixel) movement; multiply both the `sin` and `cos` by the actual distance you want it to move `endX = startX + dist * cos(angle)`.

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes, the program does have the distance in them, just forgot em on this post. i have tried with radians as well, still no dice. cos(Math.toRadiens(angle))  Does that solve the clockwise, counter clockwise issue?  im pretty sure the 0, 0 being in the upper left corner is complicating things. should i translate that point to the center of the pane, like i have done with the image, or does this not matter?

Comment: Well... works just fine for me, You should create and post a [MCVE]

Comment: You might need `setLayoutX` and `setLayoutY`, instead of `setX()` and `setY()` depending on how you have everything set up.  Again, probably best to create a complete, standalone example.